# Using Javascript in the Web Page to Prevent Page Caching

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a stand alone video playback application, i.e. run from files and not a web server, and pass variables from one page to another via localStorage.

A video whose state is currently unwatched is selected and the video player page is called to play the selected video. When the video is completed and the back button is clicked to return to the previous video selection page, the unwatched status is not being updated.

This functionality works in Chrome and Opera but not FireFox nor Safari. The whole application does not work in IE or Edge as they do not allow the use of localStorage variables with local files.

How can I get Firefox and Safari to reload the page and use the modified localStorage variables instead of using the cached version? I need something that will work from the web page code as I can not force those end users to make changes to their browser settings.

Thanks.

Comment: sounds like a chicken and egg problem. what's generating the page?

Comment: Three HTML coded pages with javascript generated code to include the values stored in localStorage. Page 1 access and displays the localStorage variable and links to Page 2. Page 2 can update the localStorage variable and links to Page 3. Page 3 can also update the localStorage variable. However, the changes made on Page 3 are not shown on Page 2 when the back button is pressed; you have to force a page refresh to see the changes. And the same is true returning to Page 1 from Page 2. Firefox and Safari appear to be using cached pages and do no show the changes to the localStorage variables.